# Testing Node ES6 Child Process

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, babeljs, child-process

I am seeking some views with regards to the title.

I have forked a child process script that is in ES6 syntax, with a few `import something from someModule`. Everything works as expected when transpiling and running the application in development mode and also when I build for production.

The problem is when running the tests; the script for the child process is not being transpiled by babel. I claim so because of the error I am getting when running the tests;

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import something from 'services/someModule';
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
```

Again, this is only happening when running tests.

The script that runs tests in `package.json` looks like this;

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=testing mocha test/**/*.js --timeout=10000 --require @babel/register --exit",

}
```

What is the way forward? Is there an option that I am missing in the testing script in order to have the forked script transpiled too?

The `.babelrc` looks like this;

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
   ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Considering that you're already using Babel, this likely means that Babel wasn't configured properly to transpile ES modules (`import`) to CJS modules (`require`).

Comment: @estus, I have just included the `.babelrc` file for the configuration.

Comment: Still seeking some guidance here. 

Comment: Babel env should work. *The problem is when running the tests; the script for the child process is not being transpiled by babel.*  - the question doesn't contain this part while it's relevant. You are spawning a process in tested app, aren't you? I have no opportunity to test this but I'd expect `--require @babel/register` to affect child process, too.